# How do you search a list for recipe's in my application

Tags: android

I am new to android and have been teaching myself how to create apps through the android developers website.  My app itself is like a recipe book.  It lets me add my favourite recipes to a database so therefore where ever I am I am able to see what ingredients and the method for creating my favourite dishes.  The list is getting rather long now so I was wondering if there was a way to search through a list like you do for contacts in your phone book. This would make things a lot easier for me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Like pressing a letter on the side of the screen associated with the beginning letter of the title of the recipe? Or something else?

Answer (score 1):

You can actually integrate the Android search box (the one that pops up when you hit the "search" hardware key) into your application, so it searches your data.  There's a page on [Using the Android Search Dialog](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html) in the Android Developer Guide.

Answer (score 0):

Also for user convenience and habbits to use search button you can override `onSearchRequested` method and do anything you want, show additional layout etc...